# Is it possible to change the 'Type' of a directory in Windows

Tags: windows-explorer, sorting

Directories in Windows are always tagged as "File folder" in the explorer:

[image: File folder]

Is it possible to edit this field? To introduce a new kind of folder?

I would like to do that in order to enable another level of sorting of directories.

i.e. first "special" directories, then regular directories, then files

Comment: Would creating your own personal ["library"](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/personalize-windows-7-by-creating-new-user-defined-libraries/) be more appropriate?

Comment: Doesn't seem fitting enough. I want regular directories there as well, I still won't be able to differentiate them

Answer (score 0):

By right-clicking the folder and selecting "Properties" a dialog will appear. Go to the "Customize" tab and you will find a drop-down list titled "Customize this folder for:". If you change the selected item, the type of the folder will change accordingly.

You may also check a [step-by-step](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16694/customize-the-five-windows-folder-templates/) tutorial and the [more in-depth info in the Microsoft knowledge base](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/812003).

Comment: Doesn't seem like the 'Type' of the folder is changed. Only the columns' customization, I'll give a more thorough look at the in-depth link